# Downloading Debian packages (for a Crunchbang install) on a Ubuntu computer

Tags: ubuntu, drivers, package-management, crunchbang

I'm trying to get the ethernet drivers on a Lenovo T440s to work, more specifically I'm trying to get the intel e1000e ethernet installed. To do that I need the `build-essential` package first, but that alone will not compile unless it has it's dependencies installed.

Is there an easy way to download all the dependencies for a package on a second Ubuntu computer for a Debian-based system (Crunchbang on a laptop lacking internet)?

Comment: I'm honestly not sure about the relationship between Debian, Crunchbang and Ubuntu, but if you have the proper apt sources set up, you should be able to make use of apt-get `--download-only` or `download` (see the apt-get man page). If it's only a single package, or a few packages (build-essential is a metapackage), then you can go to the Debian package web site and download the .debs that you need.

Comment: It probably would be a good idea to run a live cd of Crunchbang or Debian to get the downloads huh?

Comment: That does sound like it could be a workable approach.

Comment: I wouldn't do it. While Ubuntu packages in general might be compatible with Debian systems Ubuntu does change some things. Just like it isn't recommended you install Debian packages on Ubuntu, best not to do it the other way either. Just get a Debian/Crunchbang liveCD.